In Quarto, is it possible to show arbitrary text on hover?
I work on a Quarto html document and I have a list of definitions. In addition to the in-text definition, I would like to show a box with the definition on hover so that the reader does not have to navigate the document to access the definition.
In know that the YAML option crossrefs-hover: true allows to show a box with the content of a cross-reference to a section or a citation (if a .bib file is supplied to the bibliography argument in YAML) (example below).
Something close to what I wish is achieved by adding footnotes which can also be displayed on hover with footnote-hover: true (see example below). The major drawbacks to this method are:

The definition is supplied just after the word in the qmd, which makes it difficult to read when definitions are long. Since the definition is already shown in-text, it would be more convenient to refer to it like a section, figure or table.
Some terms with definitions to be displayed are used many times, so it is very inefficient to paste the definition each time the word is used.
The definition is shown when hovering on the footnote number and not the word itself (like for crossrefs-hover), which is not desirable as some definitions apply to a group of words.

My question is tehrefore : How to show arbitrary text (from somewhere else in the document) on hovering specific terms ?
Below are the different methods I found, none of which is perfect.
---
format: 
  html:
    crossrefs-hover: true
    footnote-hover: true
---

# Definitions {#sec-FirstSection}

## Term 1

Example of definition for term 1.

## Term 2 {#sec-term2}

Example of definition for term 2.

# Other section

- "See @sec-FirstSection": this method shows the section, but not the term in-text.

- "Definition for term 1^[Example of definition for term 1]": this method shows the definition as desired but is fairly inconvenient.

- "Definition for [term 2](#sec-term2)": this method creates a hyperlink to the definition, which is great to refer to it multiple times, but does not show any text on hover.

I need something in-between those methods. Do you see any workaround ?

A satisfying option can be obtained based on this example :
https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/8034
